# MSSQL SQLSVR Database Connection in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am having a problem I have been troubleshooting a while. I am trying to create a connection to a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database to use in a CodeIgniter application. Upon running that model i get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in PATH\sqlsrv_driver.php on line 76
```

Here is the important section of my database configuration file:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'HOST';
$db['default']['username'] = 'UNAME';
$db['default']['password'] = 'PWORD';
$db['default']['database'] = 'DBASE';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
```

I have followed a couple of guides here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere from Google to download the drivers needed to start the connection. Right now,

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

are in the php/ext folder and

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

have been added to my php.ini file. I have the Microsoft SQL Native Client. Am I missing anything else here? This is driving me nuts.

EDIT:
A line in my php.ini file was miss typed but I am now presented with this error:

A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\report\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 124

Comment: Do you have a `extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` line?

Comment: I was about to rage at you for not reading my question...but I realized that I miss typed it as php_pdo_54_ts.dll instead of php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll. Thank you. Next problem, Now I'm getting a CI error: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. Is this related or not?

Comment: Is your SQL Server really on a computer called `'HOST'` or did you change the settings for the purposes of this question?

Comment: For the purposed of this question. All those fields have been copied and pasted to ensure accuracy.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to show the correct `extension` line and the new error message. Also check the obvious stuff, like using `domain\user` for windows authentication if you're using that, and making sure SQL Configuration Manager has TCP turned on.

Comment: Thanks. TCP is turned on and I am using SQL Server Authentication. Could a missing instance name on my host name be causing this?